# FullAjaxExceptionHandler - Find out which component caused ViewExpiredException?

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

Is it possible to tell which component was clicked that caused the `ViewExpiredException` to be thrown when using AJAX? I'd like to avoid showing the session expired page if the user simply tried to log out and show him the normal log out page instead.

I was thinking of overriding `shouldHandleExceptionRootCause` but I cannot find anything to identify if the logout button was pressed or not.

I'm using Mojarra JSF 2.2 and Omnifaces 2.5.1.

---

**Solution**

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldHandleExceptionRootCause(FacesContext context, Throwable exception)
{
    UIComponent source = Components.getCurrentActionSource();
    if (source != null && "logout".equals(source.getId()))
    {
        NavigationHandler nh = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
        nh.handleNavigation(context, null, "logout.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return super.shouldHandleExceptionRootCause(context, exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Components`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components) utility class offers several methods to identify the currently submitted form, the currently invoked command and the source component of the action event (which can be the command component itself, but also an input component in case of an ajax event).

```
UIForm form = Components.getCurrentForm();
UICommand command = Components.getCurrentCommand();
UIComponent source = Components.getCurrentActionSource();
```

Take your pick. You could for example check the `id` of the form, command or source to see if it's the desired one.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you once again! Do I need to use something like `OmniPartialViewContext.getCurrentInstance(context).closePartialResponse();` after navigating to the logout page?

Comment: Only call `resetPartialResponse()` if exception was thrown in midst of render response and part of ajax response has already been written. Usually, this isn't true for `ViewExpiredException`.